# Performing client independent update of hash with Argon2

Tags: argon2

I'm trying to perform a hash update with updated parameters using argon2. According to [Argon spec v3](https://www.password-hashing.net/submissions/specs/Argon-v3.pdf) (`2.2.3 Client-indepentend Update`, p. 9) the client independent update is executed as follows:

$$
Tag_{new} = \Pi(Tag_{old},S,m_{new},R_{new},\tau_{new})
$$

I'm assuming $\Pi$ to be our hash fn Argon2i/Argon2d (as used in `2.4.4 Security of Argon2 to generic attacks`, p. 15) and $R_{new}$ the parallelism param.

Now, using the online tool https://argon2.online/ , I performed the following attempt:

- input `asdf` as plain text input
- input `salt11chars` as salt
- leave params as default (mode=argon2i, parallelism=1, $m=16, $$t=2$, $\tau=16$)
- calculate hash
- input calculated hash as plain text input
- increase parallelism by 1
- calculate hash
- verify if `asdf` matches the hash

$\rightarrow$ verification fails

So why is that and what am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For client independent updates with Argon2 is possible only for iteration and you need to store full output size ( 512-bit). If you look at the image at this answer, you will see [why](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/98514/18298) or [page 6](https://www.password-hashing.net/argon2-specs.pdf) see the initial hash and the first final hash.

Comment: See discussion here [Password hashing algorithms that can transform an existing hash to a different cost setting without knowledge of the password](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/258619/86735)

Comment: Thanks for your hints. Would it be possible for you to give me an example? And where have I access to the full output, given the final tag is actually a composite hash a ccording to the figure?

Comment: I don't think that Argon2 has a true client-independent update.

Comment: FYI: According to [OWASP Best Practices for Password Storage](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html#upgrading-legacy-hashes), one should hash the old hashed password with a new hash, generated by a newer hashing algorithm.
After the user enters the original password, one can hash it using only the newer hashing algorithm and store its' hash. I assume this 2 step hashing has to be included for backwards compatibility, until all users have input their original passwords at least once and generated a hash with the newer hashing algorithm.

Comment: This is *not* client independent, but the recommended way to update legacy hashes .