# Why does Argon2 truncate BLAKE2b outputs?

Tags: key-derivation, password-hashing, argon2

The Argon2 [variable-length hash function](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9106#section-3.3) uses BLAKE2b directly if the user requests an output less than or equal to 64 bytes in length. However, if the user requests an output longer than this, each BLAKE2b-512 hash is truncated to become BLAKE2b-512-256. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2#Variable-length_hash_function):

```
   // If the requested digestSize is 64-bytes or lower, then we use Blake2b directly
   if (digestSize <= 64) then
      // concatenate 32-bit little endian digestSize with the message bytes
      return Blake2b(digestSize ∥ message, digestSize)

   // For desired hashes over 64-bytes (e.g. 1024 bytes for Argon2 blocks),
   // we use Blake2b to generate twice the number of needed 64-byte blocks,
   // and then only use 32-bytes from each block

   // Calculate the number of whole blocks (knowing we're only going to use 32-bytes from each)
   r ← Ceil(digestSize/32)-2;

   // Generate r whole blocks.
   // Initial block is generated from message
   V1 ← Blake2b(digestSize ∥ message, 64);
   // Subsequent blocks are generated from previous blocks
   for i ← 2 to r do
      Vi ← Blake2b(Vi-1, 64)
   // Generate the final (possibly partial) block
   partialBytesNeeded ← digestSize – 32*r;
   Vr+1 ← Blake2b(Vr, partialBytesNeeded)

   // Concatenate the first 32-bytes of each block Vi
   // (except the possibly partial last block, which we take the whole thing)
   // Let Ai represent the lower 32-bytes of block Vi
   return A1 ∥ A2 ∥ ... ∥ Ar ∥ Vr+1
```

I didn't see any rationale for this glancing at the [specification](https://www.password-hashing.net/argon2-specs.pdf) and [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9106). Why are they not using full BLAKE2b-512 outputs?

Comment: [Because it is designed for password hashing](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/98514/18298) where there is no collision problem so 256-bit is enough for all.

Comment: @kelalaka Yes, I'm aware of that, but truncation results in more computation (more hashing) for larger outputs. Deriving a short output hasn't been slowed down. It doesn't seem like domain separation when V1 is the same as a digestSize = 64.

Comment: A by now classic remark for "why" questions: have you tried to contact the authors? If possible it would be great if they or otherwise you could post the answer here.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I haven't but seeing as nobody has answered, I'll do that. I've had mixed success emailing academics/engineers so it's not my go-to approach.

Comment: First author hasn't replied so will try the other two.

Comment: Second author also hasn't replied.

Comment: Emailed all three authors and none have responded. I tried.